# system specを通したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

■背景
某スクールでの課題に取り組んでおります。
期限があるのですが、スクールメンターの回答が遅いのでこちらで質問させてください。

■実現したいこと
このテストコードをsystemspecとして通したい

■現状
Rspecが通したいのですが、しかし通らず。以下質問させてください。
bundle exec rspec実行で以下のエラーが起きます。

エラーメッセ
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
Unable to find link

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■実際に試したこと
エラーメッセージで検索をかけ、
以下を参考にリンクにidをつけてみましたが、失敗（加えて今まで通っていたテストが通らなくなり悪化）
https://www.halu.dev/entry/2015/11/17/210904

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■その他参考画像
spec_helper
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
rails_helper
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■コード
HTMLのコード

```
<% provide(:title, @product.name) %>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <section class="lightSection clearfix pageHeader">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="page-title">
            <h2><%= @product.name %></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <ol class="breadcrumb pull-right">
            <li><%= link_to 'Home', potepan_path %></li>                          
            <li class="active"><%= @product.name %></li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>     
  <section class="mainContent clearfix">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row singleProduct">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left productSlider">
              <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <% @product.images.each_with_index do |image, i| %>
                    <div class="item <%= "active" if i.zero? %>">
                      <%= image_tag(image.attachment(:large)) %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix">
                <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <% @product.images.each_with_index do |image, i| %>
                      <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="<%= i %>" class="thumb">
                        <%= image_tag(image.attachment(:small)) %>
                      </div>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>
                  <%= link_to potepan_category_path(@product.taxons.first.id) do%>
                    <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i>一覧ページへ戻る
                  <% end %>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <h2><%= @product.name %></h2>
              <h3><%= @product.display_price %></h3>
              <p><%= @product.description %></p>
              <span class="quick-drop">
                <select name="guiest_id3" id="guiest_id3" class="select-drop">
                  <option value="0">S</option>
                  <option value="1">M</option>
                  <option value="2">L</option>
                  <option value="3">XL</option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <span class="quick-drop resizeWidth">
                <select name="guiest_id4" id="guiest_id4" class="select-drop">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <div class="btn-area">
                <a href="cart_page.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">カートへ入れる<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

rspecのコード

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Products", type: :system do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  describe "GET #show" do
    let(:image) { create(:image) }
    let(:product) { create(:product, taxons: [taxon]) }
    let(:taxonomy) { create(:taxonomy) }
    let(:taxon) { create(:taxon, taxonomy: taxonomy) }
    
    before do
      product.images << image
      get potepan_product_path(product.id)
      # 画像URL取得が上手くいかない問題への対応
      # https://mng-camp.potepan.com/curriculums/document-for-final-task-2#notes-of-image-test
      ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url
    end

    it "一覧ページに戻るをクリックすると商品カテゴリページへアクセスされていること" do
      click_link('my_id')
      expect(current_path).to eq potepan_category_path(taxons.id)
    end

    it "ページが表示されていること" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "商品の名前が表示されていること" do
      expect(response.body).to include product.name
    end

    it "商品の価格が表示されていること" do
      expect(response.body).to include product.display_price.to_s
    end

    it "商品の説明が表示されていること" do
      expect(response.body).to include product.description
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/84ig2z2hkj2362) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

visit 該当path

でテスト通りました